# Reconnecting automatically in psycopg2 and python after database restart

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

We have a database singleton something like this which is being used in a python project. We would like to reestablish connection to the database automatically when the database is shut down and restarted. What is the best way to do this?

We are thinking of putting some logic in getconn function. We first do a SELECT 1, trap the psycopg2 error and call another function to reset the connection pool. Note that our application is multithreaded and multiple threads can access the class at the same time. This is why there is a lock in the "new" function.

```
class DBConnection:
    _instance = None
    logger: logging.Logger = None

    def __new__(cls, logger1: logging.Logger):
        dbConnLock.acquire()
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = object.__new__(cls)
            try:
                max_conn = 64
                keepalive_args = {"keepalives": 1, "keepalives_idle": 25, "keepalives_interval": 4,
                                  "keepalives_count": 9}
                print("starting creating pool")
                DBConnection._instance.pool = psycopg2.pool.ThreadedConnectionPool(5, 64, database='',
                                                                                   host='',
                                                                                   user='',
                                                                                   password='',
                                                                                   application_name='',
                                                                                   sslmode='require', connect_timeout=5,
                                                                                   **keepalive_args)
                logger1.info("Connection pool started")
                print("End creating pool")

            except Exception as ex:
                DBConnection._instance = None
                dbConnLock.release()
                raise ex
            cls._instance.__init__(logger1)
        dbConnLock.release()
        return cls._instance

    def __init__(self, logger1):
        self.logger = logger1

    def getconn(self, p_key):
        ps_connection = self._instance.pool.getconn(p_key)
        ps_cursor = ps_connection.cursor()
        ps_connection.autocommit = True
        self.logger.debug('Entering ' + str(p_key)+' '+ hex(id(ps_connection)))
        return ps_connection, ps_cursor

    def putconn(self, p_key, ps_connection, ps_cursor):
        if ps_cursor is not None:
            ps_cursor.close()
        if (ps_cursor is not None) and (ps_connection is not None):
            self._instance.pool.putconn(ps_connection, p_key)
        self.logger.debug('Exiting ' + str(p_key)+' '+hex(id(ps_connection)))

    def __del__(self):
        self._instance.pool.closeall()
        self.logger.info("Removing connection pool")
```

Comment: well, you can add a method `check_availabilty` which check if db is up or not. and based on it give connection

Comment: Might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62094660/psycopg2-auto-reconnect-inside-a-class/62100995#62100995